# How do I get anchor href value on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have an anchor like this:

```
<a onClick="return confirm('Sure?')" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Click here</a>
```

Is there anyway I can get the value of href "http://stackoverflow.com/" when I click "Click here"? Bearing in mind that I don't have other attributes to help, such as id or name!

I'm overriding the confirm function and I need to redirect the user to the location provided in the anchor if they clicked ok as follows:

```
window.confirm = function(msg) {
      var targetUrl = jQuery(this).attr("href");
      jQuery("#alert_box").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         show: "slide",
         modal: true,
         width: 400,
         resizable:false,
         title: '<img src="icons/confirm.png" /> Confirm!',
         buttons: { "Cancel": function() { 
                        jQuery(this).dialog("close");                       
                    },
                 "OK": function() { 
                        //jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                        jQuery(location).attr('href', targetUrl);
                    }
                   }
      });

      jQuery("#alert_box").html(msg);
      jQuery("#alert_box").dialog("open");
      return false;
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Fyi, if you wrap your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);` you can use `$` instead of writing `jQuery` everytime even if you used `$.noConflict()` to restore the global `$` var.

Comment: It is a bad idea to replace `window.confirm()`. The original function is not asynchronous, i.e. you can do `if(confirm(...))` - however, it's impossible to do the same thing in a replacement function. And while monkeypatching is sometimes fine, monkeypatching in a way that breaks code not knowing about the fact that the function has been replaced is bad.

Answer (score 3):

To redirect a user use:

```
window.location.href = targetUrl;
```

instead of:

```
jQuery(location).attr('href', targetUrl);
```

Also it is a good idea remove inline JavaScript, for example:

```
<a class="confirm" href="http://www.example.com">..</a>

// script.js
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    }
});
```

Also `this` inside your confirm function declaration is not referred to the `<a>` element. You may want to use something like:

```
<a onclick="return confirm(this, 'Sure?')" href="...">...</a>

// script.js
function confirm(e, msg) {
    var targetUrl = $(e).href('attr');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tarkus and ThiefMaster for your replies. First of all I wanted to say that I'm well aware that using inline javascript is not a good habit and overriding confirm is not a good idea either, as ThiefMaster mentioned above. However, I've just taken on a big project with almost thousands of files which makes it impossible to go through each and everyone and changing it to the way it should be!Secondly, in the example I gave above the "targetUrl" comes back as blank which means that jQuery(this).attr("href"); is not working! Any ideas why??!

Comment: How about: <a onclick="return confirm(this, 'Are you sure?')" ... > and add one more argument to your confirm function.

Comment: I'd love to but there's no chance in such a short space of time to go through all the files and add "this". If I was able to I would've added a "class" or "id" attribute which would make life a lot easier, but I thought that there was a short workaround which I could get away with now :-( Anyway, I'd like to thank you guys very much for your time, contributions and advices.